# Show that $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{R},\,\cdot\,)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The only thing I know about $(\Bbb{R},\,\cdot\,)$ is that it is isomorphic to $GL_n (\Bbb{R}) / SL_n (\Bbb{R})$.
In general, I find it difficult to show that there is an isomorphism between two groups, unless they are cosciennt groups. That is easier because I can use the isomorphism theorems, but when I fall into these cases, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I don't know about your statement, but $x\mapsto e^x$ gives an isomorphism $(R,+)\to(R_{>0},*)$

Comment: What is the group operation on $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$? It can't be multiplication as $0$ has no inverse.

Comment: In fact, $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+)$, for it contains an element of order $2$ (aka "$-1$").

Answer (score 1):

As I am also studying some of these, I would like to share some tips that I found useful.

First of all, you could begin writing an homomorphism. In your example, it might help writing $\phi:(\mathbb{R,+})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R,\times})$ such that $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ with $x,y\in(\mathbb{R},+)$. Now it's clearer that you may want to seek something with exponentials. Now prove that it's actually a bijective map, thus an isomorphism.

Also simplifying the problem might help. From your example, we found that there's an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R,+})$ and $(\mathbb{R_{>0},\times})$. Now how could we extend it to negative numbers?

> Or how could we prove that we *can't* do it (which is your case)?

Having a picture may also help if you have simpler sets. For example, showing that there's an homomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(\mathbb{C}):=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$. A picture of $\mu(\mathbb{C})$ will show that you need to map all real numbers to the unit circle in the complex plane. Thus, you'll likely think about a trigonometric circle in the complex plane.

Also, using the isomorphism theorems will help. For example, from the above example, you'll find that a clever choice of $\theta$ and direct application of the First Isomorphism Theorem will hold that $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mu(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm essentially just synopsizing the comments, it seems. Firstly, $(\mathbf{R},\cdot)$ is not a group - at least not in the way that it seems you want to define it. As we know, there does not exist $k\in \mathbf{R}$ such that $0\cdot k=1$. That is, $0$ can not be inverted under multiplication. This is already a problem.

Now, $(\mathbf{R}\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ makes sense as a group, but we can't create an isomorphism $(\mathbf{R},+)$ to $(\mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$. To see this, suppose such an isomorphism $\phi$ existed, where $\phi: (\mathbf{R},+)\to (\mathbf{R}\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. Then fix $\varphi^{-1}(-1)$. It must be the case that $\varphi^{-1}(-1)+\varphi^{-1}(-1)=0$ but this implies that $\varphi^{-1}(-1)=0,$ which would in turn imply that $0\mapsto -1$. This is a contradiction, since a homomorphism of groups must send the identity to the identity. The multiplicative identity is $1$.

So, the only exercise which makes sense is to show that $(\mathbf{R},+)\cong (\mathbf{R}_{>0}, \cdot).$ In this case, it is fairly routine to check that $x\mapsto e^x$ is the requisite isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot show that $(\mathbb R, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$ because it isn't.

For one, $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$ is not even a group! So the question is kind of nonsensical. If you remove the problematic $0$ to make the group $(\mathbb R - \{0\}, \cdot)$, then we still have elements of order $2$ (i.e. any negative number). No such elements exist in $(\mathbb R,+)$.

On the other hand, $(\mathbb R, +)$ embeds as a subgroup of $(\mathbb R - \{0\}, \cdot)$ via the homomorphism:
\begin{align}
f : (\mathbb R, +) &\rightarrow (\mathbb R, \cdot) \\
x &\mapsto e^x
\end{align}
Checking that it's a homomorphism:
$$f(xy) = f(x+y) = e^{x+y} = e^x e^y = f(x)f(y)$$

Comment: After showing that it is homomorphism, in order to prove it is isomorphic do you need to prove that f is bijective?

Comment: @vyavarignut - if a homomorphism is injective, then the range of that homomorphism is isomorphic to its domain. So yes.